# How to keep std::thread from freezing GUI in QT?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am working on a project where I will be ingesting multiple binary files, decode them, and convert their data into a CSV. I figured the quickest way to do this would be to thread the work. Simply load the files into a queue, have the threads grab a file, work on it, convert it, output it, and then die.

What I wrote actually works great, however, I cannot figure out how to get the GUI to be responsive as I have a progress bar that I would like to update or simply have the user move the GUI to a corner while it processes the data. And I believe this is because `std::thread` is just hanging up the GUI.

In my code I have the following function once a button is pressed to execute:

```
void MyExtractor::on_Execute_clicked()
{
    QStringList binary = tlmFiles.entryList(QStringList() << "*.bin",QDir::Files);
    queue.clear();
    threadPool.clear();

    if(binary.size() != 0)
    {

        foreach(QString filename, binary)
        {
            queue.emplace_back(inputDir + '/' + filename);
        }

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i)
        {
            threadPool.emplace_back(&MyExtractor::initThread,this,std::ref(queue),std::ref(mut));
        }

    }
    else
    {
        message.setText("No binary files found! Please select another folder!");
        message.exec();
    }

    for (auto &&e : threadPool)
    {
        e.join();
    }
}
```

And initThread looks like this:

```
void MyExtractor::initThread(std::deque<QString> &queue, std::mutex &mutex)
{
    QString file;
    QString toOutput = outputDir;

    while(queue.size() > 0)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            if(!queue.empty())
            {
                file = queue.front();
                queue.pop_front();
            }
        }
        BitExtract *bitExtractor = new BitExtract();
        if(file.size() != 0)
        {
            bitExtractor->extract(file,toOutput);
        }
        delete bitExtractor;
    }

}
```

I have been reading about QThreads. And from what I think I have been reading, it seems I need to create a separate thread to watch the work, and the other thread to watch the GUI? I am not sure if I have worded that correctly. However, I am not even sure how to go about that since I am using a `std::thread` to do the conversion, and I am not sure how well `QThread` will play with this. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I should make it clear that `threadPool` is a `std::vector<std::thread>`

Comment: You need to get rid of `e.join();` the GUI will be frozen waiting for the threads to finish.

Comment: @drescherjm won’t that just lead to dangling threads when I exit the program? How will the threads know when to die?

Comment: You can put that in your destructor for your class.

Comment: it might be better for you to pass each thread its own smaller queue of items rather then one shared queue. I dont see you doing any locking when clearing/building the queue which means clicking that button multiple times will result in undefined behavior. Its also dangerous to pass a reference to a thread. If you do this you wont need a mutex either.

Comment: @drescherjm I didn’t think to do that! I’ll give that a whirl.

Comment: @BradAllred I plan to grey the button out so that way the user can’t have any interaction with the execute button until the work is done.

Comment: @Sailanarmo still, you may want to consider that design change. its simpler code to understand and keep bug free, I wouldn't be surprised if it is faster too (totally depends on the work being done) mutex contention and copying your `QString` can be very costly. If they had their own queues you would not need to copy the string. You are also creating a new bit extractor every loop which seems unnecessary. There is also no reason you cant create that on the stack rather then the heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by @drescherjm, your problem is here:

```
for (auto &&e : threadPool)
{
    e.join();
}
```

`join()` won't return until the thread has completed, which means your GUI thread will be blocked inside that for-loop until all threads have exited, which is what you want to avoid.  (it's always desirable for any function in the main/Qt/GUI thread to return as quickly as possible, so that Qt's GUI event loop can remain responsive)

Avoiding that is fairly straightforward -- instead of calling `join()` right after the threads have been spawned, you should only call `join()` on a thread after the thread has notified you that it has completed its work and is about to exit.  That way `join()` will never take more than a few milliseconds to return.

As for how to get a `std::thread` to notify your main/GUI thread that it has finished its task, one simple way to do it is to have your `std::thread` call [QApplication::postEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) just before it exits, and override the [event(QEvent *)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#event) virtual method on (whatever object you passed in as the first argument to postEvent()) to handle the posted event-object (note that you can make your own subclass of `QEvent` that contains whatever data you want to send to the GUI thread) by calling `join()` on the `std::thread`, plus whatever cleanup and result-handling code you need to execute after a thread has returned its result.